# How to force sound to play when adjusting notification volume

Tags: android, audio, notifications, volume

I have an activity that uses

this.setVolumeControlStream(AudioManager.STREAM_NOTIFICATION);

so that the volume control rocker adjusts the notification volume instead of the ringer volume.

This works fine, but when the rocker is used to adjust the notification volume I'd like a sound to be played back at the new volume - as happens when adjusting the ringer volume. And this isn't happening for me.

What's the best way to make this happen?

BTW, if it's relevant, I's like this to work in Android 2.3.6.

Thanks,

Martin

Comment: Couldn't you use a `MediaPlayer` or `AudioTrack` to play some kind of beep after changing the volume?